# Getting Gson MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson

I am creating a custom keyboard app. In the `onCreateInputView` method I have the following code inside of a coroutine that parses a file (using `JsonParser` from the Gson library) from https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/index.json.

```
Log.d("VED-APP","Parsing File From Github")
JsonParser().parse(fetchString("https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/index.json"))
```

where `fetchString()` is the following method:

```
private suspend fun fetchString(url: String): String = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    url.httpGet().header(Pair("pragma", "no-cache"), Pair("cache-control", "no-cache")).responseString { _, _, result ->
        //Log.d("VED-APP", r.toString())

        when (result) {
            is Result.Failure -> {
                cont.resumeWithException(result.getException())
            }
            is Result.Success -> {
                cont.resume(result.value)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The above code works fine without any errors. I can successfully parse the file located at the URL using Gson.

However, I get an exception when I try to parse the file (with the same exact contents) from a local source, instead of github, with the following code.

```
val layoutFileName = "index.json"
val layoutFile =  File(filesDir, layoutFileName)


        //If layout file does not exist, create it and write default layout to file.
        if(!layoutFile.exists()) {
            Log.d("VED-APP","FILE DOES NOT EXIST")
            layoutFile.writeText(resources.getString(R.string.default_keyboard_layout))
        } else {
            Log.d("VED-APP","FILE EXISTS")

        }

        Log.d("VED-APP","Parsing Local File")
       JsonParser().parse(FileReader(layoutFile))
```

The exception is:

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated array at line 1 column 18 path $.Excited[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpr3c.png)

Here is the contents of the entry `default_keyboard_layout` in `strings.xml`:
[image: Screenshot_Of_Strings.xml]

This is very odd because the contents of the `default_keyboard_layout` entry in `strings.xml` is the exact same as the contents of the index.json file on github.

I did some debugging and I think I found the source of the error.
I added this into my code in order to view the contents of `index.json` before it gets parsed

```
layoutFile.forEachLine {
            Log.d("VED-APP",it)
        }
```

and I got the following result:

```
 { Excited:[https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Happy/excited1.gif, https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Happy/excited2.gif, https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Happy/excited3.gif], Sad:[https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad1.gif, https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad2.gif, https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad3.gif, https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad4.gif] }
```

Two things are odd about this output.

1) Everything is on one line, although the entry in `strings.xml` and the file on github are both multiline

2) The file has no quotation marks although the entry in `strings.xml` and the file on github do have quotation marks.

I suspect these two issues are the source of the problem, but I'm not sure.

Why am I getting this exception and how do I fix it?

Update 1 -

I tried Tynn's solution, by changing my `strings.xml` too

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Anime Face Keyboard</string>
    <string name="subtype_en_US">English (US)</string>
    <string name="default_keyboard_layout"><![CDATA[{
    "Excited":["https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Happy/excited1.gif",
                "https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Happy/excited2.gif",
                "https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Happy/excited3.gif"],

    "Sad":["https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad1.gif",
            "https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad2.gif",
            "https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad3.gif",
            "https://github.com/vedantroy/image-test/raw/master/Sad/sad4.gif"]
}]]></string>
</resources>
```

but that did nothing.

I printed the value of `resources.getString(R.string.default_keyboard_layout)` and it was still missing quotes and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to escape the `"` as `\"` and the new-lines as `\n`.

As the strings are defined in *XML* the new-lines are regarded as part of the mark-up and the `"` are used to define the string containing mark-up like for example a space-break at the end of the line:

```
<string name="a">a </string>
<string name="b">"b "</string>
```

Here `a` is just `"a"` while `b` is `"b "`.

```
<string>"{\n
    \"key\": [\"value\"]\n
}\n"</string>
```

Comment: Hmm.... that didn't work. I updated my post with my implementation of your solution.

Comment: Sorry for that. Anyway, consider escaping the characters.